# Complex integration of an oscillatory function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, oscillatory-integral

I've been trying to find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(x^{3}+y x^{2}+y^{2} x)}dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x e^{i(x^{3}+y x^{2}+y^{2} x)}dx$. I've been doing the integral numerically but I'm not sure if they can be done by contour integration. Any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Which is the variable of integration in these? $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Is the measure of the integral $dx$ or $dy$? Either way, you could use Euler's formula and then with some help from Wolfram, get your answer in terms of Fresnel $C$ and $S$ integrals which have the properties $C(\pm\infty)=\pm\frac{1}{2}$ and $S(\pm\infty)=\pm\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @saulspatz It's wrt  x, I should've added that.